# How to run a process in background and change directory in the same command-line

Tags: bash

I would like to create a command that will change directory, run a process in the background and then return to the original directory. It is important for the process to be started from a specific directory (It uses the running directory for relative paths).

I tried running this, but got the following error:

```
cd ~/work; myapp &> /dev/null &; cd -
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I can run either of the following commands.

```
# Without the "&" that cause the process to run in the background
cd ~/work; myapp &> /dev/null; cd -
# Without the " cd -" which returns my to the original directory
cd ~/work; myapp &> /dev/null &
```

The purpose of this, is to be able to add this command to my aliases.

Comment: Related cross StackExchange site:[How to write a for loop which runs an asynchronous command in each iteration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392951/43400) \(You can use the same trick for your question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the `cd` command and `myapp` in the same subshell and you do not need to `cd` back:

```
( cd ~/work; myapp &>/dev/null ) &
```

Parentheses, `(...)`, create a subshell.  You can freely change directories (`cd`) or change the environment in a subshell and it will have no effect on the parent shell.  Thus, there is no need to `cd` back afterward.

#### Example

Let's start from the directory `/tmp/1`:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/1
```

Now, let's run `cd` and a sample command in a background shell and then check the directory again:

```
$ ( cd work; date &>/dev/null ) &
[1] 11942
$ pwd
/tmp/1
```

Comment: Very clean and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted from this [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) page,

> A `list` is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or a newline.
>
> Of these list operators, `&&` and `||` have equal precedence, followed by `;` and `&`, which have equal precedence. If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a sub-shell. This is known as executing the command in the `background`

Which you can infer from above is that `&` is by itself a command separator just like `;`. You just need to do

```
cd ~/work; myapp &> /dev/null & cd -
#                            ^^^ just acting as a command-separator
```

(or) group your commands into compound statements using `{}` as below

```
cd ~/work; { myapp &> /dev/null & }; cd -
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks! But I'll go with John1024 approach since it is more clean.